# How do you find your home bed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I got lost with an inventory full of stuff and I don't want to kill myself. I've built a huge structure, but I'm unable to find it, as I've no idea where to go. I've slept in the bed, and tried `/spawnpoint`, but it simply just reassigned my spawnpoint.

I just want to find the coordinates of my bed, as it's the only one in the world. I've tried X-ray programs as well as Blockfinder 0.9.1 (which I can't get to work), and I just can't locate it anywhere.

I'm using Minecraft 1.5.1. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: If your bed is near your initial spawn, build a compass. It will point back to where you very first spawned.

Comment: Do you think that I would ask if it would be near spawn? @mikeTheLiar

Comment: You didn't specify. No need to be snippy.

Comment: Can't you just go into creative mode?

Comment: @DanielPalamarchuk done it, what is the point of flying around in an endless world?

Comment: If you haven't done `/spawnpoint`, you could just do `/gamerule keepInventory true` so items will not be dropped when you die.

Comment: You could look for your home in the air @Christian, instead in the thicket below. Next time you go out, leave a path of torches behind you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/), you can go back to your original spawn point by using "Move Spawn Point" on the hotbar and select "Goto Spawn". Then you can follow your history to try to figure out where your bed is.

If you really can't figure out, you can try the following MCEdit Filter. It will help you find your bed, but may actually take quite long (probably no less than a few minutes).

```
displayName = "Find beds"

inputs = (
    ("Search the whole world regardless of bounding box", True),
)

def perform(level, box, options):
    if options["Search the whole world regardless of bounding box"]:
        i = level.getAllChunkSlices()
    else:
        i = level.getChunkSlices(box)
    print "Finding beds..."
    for (chunk, slices, point) in i:
        if blockExistInChunk(chunk, 26):
            (x, z) = chunk.chunkPosition
            print "=> Bed found near x={0}, z={1}".format(x * 16 + 8, z * 16 + 8)
    print "Stopped finding beds."

def blockExistInChunk(chunk, blockId):
    for a in chunk.Blocks:
        for b in a:
            for c in b:
                if c == blockId:
                    return True
    return False
```

Save the file under the `filters` directory in MCEdit with name `findbeds.py`, then go to MCEdit, use `Filter` on the hotbar, select `Find Beds` and click `Filter`. Now watch the console (the white on black window) and it will output the approximate coordinates of where beds are found.

Sample output:

```
Finding beds...
=> Bed found near x=-440, z=-600
Stopped finding beds.
```

Comment: @Christian I believe that's Python, actually.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie oh, I was just thinking that it's java, as minecraft is mainly coded in java and so is MCedit

Comment: @Christian Programs that accept user scripts usually heavily sandbox them and use a different language than their native language, because it's less of a security risk, and because some languages are more suited to scripting than others. (If you see a program running scripts in the same language as it's written, that's often a sign of an untrustworthy program!)

Comment: I thought MCEdit is actually fully written in Python... @SevenSidedDie

Answer (score 8):

- Use <kbd>F3</kbd> to determine your present coordinates.
- Make a chest (or two).
- Put all items in your chest.
- Kill yourself.
- Note coordinates of your bed (to avoid this in the future)
- Go to your chests.
- celebrate with fireworks....

Comment: This answer will simply not work because OP has already done `/spawnpoint` once so dying will not respawn to his bed, but instead to the newly set spawn point.

Comment: This is a good answer, as it will work on future.

Answer (score 3):

Load your map into [McEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/) - this will let you fly around in the world and look for your bed. When you find it just put down your character there, load the map in regular Minecraft and you should be fine.

Press F3 after this and check the beds coordinates, write them down in case of future situations like this.

Comment: How does "Flying around in the world" differ from just using creative?

Comment: I didn't know you could load Survival maps into Creative and vice versa. That would be an equally good option. I would make a backup of the map before trying anything though, just to be sure. Good luck!

Comment: Actually, MCEdit will only load chunks you have already generated in the game and also is much easier to use to explore and find large structures that you have been to them in the game.

Comment: Thanks for that MCEdit helped me find the houses I'd built with my four year old. (we'd lost them by exploring a bit too much)

Answer (score 1):

If you're playing single player, before you go flying all over the place -- take a look at your maps directory, and figure out what blocks you've been to before.

As you've said that you've built a substantial structure, it's possible that the map file for that section will be larger than the others, but I'm not sure if you can rely on that.

Depending on when you were last at your base, you might be able to use each block's file modification times to determine likely candidates, or at the very least eliminate the ones that you know are older than when you last visited.

Answer (score -1):

With cheats on, use the command, `/give your_username  137 1`. This will give you a command block. Place down the command block and enter into it, `/gamerule keepInventory true`. Then, place a button on the command block, and press it. This will make you keep your inventory when you die, so you can know use the `/kill` command and respawn back at your bed. The one downside to this is you always keep your items on death unless you find and break the command block. I would suggest you write down the coordinates of the command block, so that you can go back later and destroy it. Make sure you have a way to find your bed again when you do this.

Comment: If you have access to the `/give` command, then you also have access to the `/gamerule` command.  No need to spawn in a command block.

Comment: [I've already pointed out the gamerule method in a comment.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/110342/finding-your-home-bed-on-minecraft#comment148374_110342) BTW this answer will simply **not** work because OP has already done `/spawnpoint` so dying will not respawn to his bed. Also, destroying the command block will **not** reset the gamerule and you need to execute `/gamerule keepInventory false` to revert the setting.